# db is not defined - initializeOrderedBulkOp()

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm having an issue with mongodb/meteorangular where i get db is not defined when trying to do a bulk operation.

My model is as follow :

```
Tests = new Mongo.Collection('tests');
```

My call :

```
 var bulk = db.collection('tests').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
       ............
       ............
    bulk.execute();
```

Is this function even usable with meteor ? doesn't look like i have a typo either.

Would appreciate the help

Comment: It is available, but you can only use on the "server" side and not in the "client" ( browser ). It takes a little doing, but it can be done if that is where you intend to use it.

Comment: yep trying that right now.i got the " only on server " error when doing the right formula, ill update the post when done if i succeed.

Comment: Well "only on server" means what it says. You cannot use this in "minimongo" ( which is the browser side library ). If instead you want a call to execute directly from the "server" then that is another thing entirely, and relatively simple to do. Just as long as you get the underlying `collection` or `database` object from the driver instead of using the `Meteor.collection` interface.

Comment: Well , i'm actually seeding my database from callbacks from a ressource outside of my app. I was doing it client side because it was easier but was planning on moving everything to the server. I've justnot used meteor server yet but it's better/mendatory if everything is there since my callbacks can also delete things in my DB but i thought it would be a publish/sub kind of deal.

Comment: Wait as second here, *"resource outside of my app"*? So are you using meteor to perform this seeding or not? If you just want a seperate seeding application, then why use meteor at all? Just create a separate data seeding application that uses the driver directly. If that is actually your intent then tagging with "meteor" is really confusing the issue. You need to make a concrete descision on how you are doing it and then implement as appropriate. Minimongo should not really ever support this (IMHO) since "bulk" actions (typically) should not come from a remote (browser) client.

Comment: I'm using meteor with an external API as a way to work on said api data. so i'm seeding my db in mongo from the api to lessen the charge, user does what he wants with the data then send it back to the api(where all the proper checks happens). So everytime there is new data in the api i get a callback that push the data into my mongodb/or delete if it's removed from api.so not really " seeding" . I'm almost there. just need to wrap my callbacks in a Fiber and it's done i think ;/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @blakes. That "Tests" collections has actually been declared. The following article is quite helpful:

http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/structure/

The essence of the article. ie declarasi used for client side and server side please put in the folder `/lib`.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

On the server ( won't work on the client ):

```
Tests = new Mongo.Collection('tests');
```

Instead of :

```
var bulk = db.collection('tests').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

do

```
var bulk = Tests.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
```

And instead of

```
bulk.execute();
```

Do

```
Meteor.wrapAsync(bulk.execute)();
```